# Why can't I save values in Session to later use in other pages?

Tags: php

I have an admin page where I want to add new products. There is a dropdown options menu where the user selects which type of products he wants to add. I want to save the value of the dropdown in $_SESSION['productType']. When the form is submitted the user is redirected to a new page where they can add the new product depending of the selected type which is supposed to be stored in $_SESSION['productType'] but it is not.

This is the html of the dropdown select:

```
<form action="AddNewItem.php" method="post">
        <select name = "option" class="form-select mx-auto" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option value="Foods">Foods</option>
            <option value="Toys">Toys</option>
            <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
        </select>
        <input  onclick="location.href='AddNewItem.php';" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" value="Add new Item">
</form>
```

Here I add the value from the form to the $_SESSION:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['option']))
{
   $option = $_POST['option'];
   $_SESSION['productType'] = $option;
   exit();
}
```

And here I try to get the value from the $_SESSION to check what type of product the user selected so I can hide the inputs for different type of products:

```
<div class="form-group" <?php if($_SESSION['productType'] != 'Foods') echo 'hidden';?>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `hidden` is not a valid attribute for a div. Did you mean to type `style="display: hidden"`?

Comment: @DarkBee It gives a notice: Notice: Undefined index: productType in C:\wamp64\www\Shop\AddNewItem.php on line 53

Answer (score -1):

Can you try removing `onclick="location.href='AddNewItem.php';"` from the input element?

It looks like you are navigating to the new page on submit rather than submitting the form.

Comment: It still does not work. I used var_dump($_SESSION) on the new page and $_SESSION is empty

Comment: What if you var_dump($_POST) ?

Comment: I do not know what is happening. I have deleted everything that is redirecting the user to the new page so I can check the var_dump($_POST) but it still redirects me and I can not see the var_dump.

Comment: In which files are each of your code snippets located?

The one where you add the value to the session should be in, or included in: "AddNewItem.php"